# sqoop export: how to export string field in hive to mysql in timestamp

Tags: sqoop

I have a hive table having a field `emp_hsu_ts` as String. It has the values in the following format `2016-12-29 12:35:44.0` . my requirement is to export this data in mysql table where field corresponding `emp_hsu_ts` in mysql has type timestamp. but when i try to export this data using `sqoop` it gives me the error

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check failed map task logs
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: '2016-12-29 12:35:44.0'
    at emp_adi_4.__loadFromFields(emp_adi_4.java:467)
    at emp_adi_4.parse(emp_adi_4.java:385)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:83)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at emp_adi_4.__loadFromFields(emp_adi_4.java:457)
    ... 12 more
```

could anyone please help?

Comment: post the `sqoop` commands/options....

Comment: this is the command i am using

Comment: this is the command i am using                                                                  sqoop --options-file sqoopexportopt.txt \
 --table emp \
 --enclosed-by '\"' \
 --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/adimendy.db/emp/gender=F  \
 --input-fields-terminated-by  ","

Comment: and your file has `2016-12-29 12:35:44.0` as string? ending with `.0` ? tht is making this data invalid - you should clean up ending `.0` using hive/spark/mapreduce before running export

Comment: for example .... `create table mysqlReady as select col1, col2, substring(emp_hsu_ts, 1,LENGTH(emp_hsu_ts)-2) from emp` and then export `mysqlReady` table/dir